# Task does not complete when showing splash screen

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

I am developing and application that loads a large amount of front end data when the program is opened. To let the user know the program has started I want to show a splash screen while it checks for the user login as well as load additional information. The issue I am having is I can't get the splash screen to stay visible with out dead locking the application.

```
public ProgramMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadDataAsync().Wait();
    _viewPageManager = new ViewPageManager(MainTabControl);
}

protected async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    StartUp.StartUpForm progressForm = new StartUp.StartUpForm();
    progressForm.Show();
    // 'await' long-running method by wrapping inside Task.Run
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {                
        AppSetting setting = new AppSetting();
        SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(setting.GetConnectionString("cn"));
        if(!helper.HandShake())
        {
            UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin();
            if(userLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Logged In");
                return Task.FromResult(true);
            }
            else
            {
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }
    }
    ).ContinueWith(new Action<Task>(task =>
    {
        //if (this.IsHandleCreated)
        // Close modal dialog
        // No need to use BeginInvoke here
        //   because ContinueWith was called with TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        progressForm.Close();

    }), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: Show us your actual `Main` method.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run` in `LoadDataAsync` when that method is already an `async Task` method?

Comment: Why do you think you should show dialogs in the Task.Run? You're not on a UI thread. And if a messagepump is running (by the `ShowDialog()`), it will block that `Task.Run`-thread. (probably a threadpool-thread). The `LoadDataAsync().Wait();` will block the current thread to wait on that task to complete. I don't see any use of using `Task.Run` here.

Comment: UI elements should only be created, accessed, and/or updated on the UI thread. Don't do it in a `Task.Run`.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
public class ProgramStartUp : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
     protected override void OnCreateSplashScreen()
     {
         SplashScreen = new StartUp.StartUpForm();            
     }

     protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
     {
         var task = Task.Run(() => LoadDataAsync());
         task.Wait();
         MainForm = new ProgramMain();
     }
     
     protected async Task LoadDataAsync()
     {
         // 'await' long-running method by wrapping inside Task.Run
         bool handshakeSuccessful = await Task.Run(() =>
         {
             AppSetting setting = new AppSetting();
             SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(setting.GetConnectionString("cn"));
             if (!helper.HandShake())
             {
                 UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin();
                 if (userLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                 {                                                
                     return true;
                 }
             }
             return false;
         });
     }
}
```

### Edit to keep UI on the same thread

I am new to using threads so let me know if this is correct.

```
 protected override void OnCreateMainForm()
{
SystemUsers users = new SystemUsers();

var progress = new Progress<LoginStatus>();
LoginStatus status = new LoginStatus();
while (status != LoginStatus.Success || status == LoginStatus.Disconnected)
{
    if (status != LoginStatus.Failure) { status = Task.Run(async () => await users.Login(progress)).GetAwaiter().GetResult(); }
    string userName = "";
    string password = "";
    if (status == LoginStatus.Failure)
    {
        UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin(users);
        if (userLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Continue)
        {
            userName = userLogin.UserName;
            password = userLogin.Password;
        }
        else
        {
            status = LoginStatus.Disconnected;
        }
        status = Task.Run(async () => await users.Login(progress, userName, password)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (status == LoginStatus.Failure)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Incorrect Username or Password Entered", "Invlaid User Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}


MainForm = new StruHubMain(users);
}


public async Task<LoginStatus> Login(IProgress<LoginStatus> progress)
{
LoginStatus loginStatus = new LoginStatus();
loginStatus = LoginStatus.Attempt;
if (progress != null) { progress.Report(loginStatus); }
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    AppSetting setting = new AppSetting();
    SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(setting.GetConnectionString("cn"));
    if (helper.HandShake())
    {
        setting.SaveConnectionString("conn", setting.GetConnectionString("conn"));
        _currentUser = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
        if (_users == null && fillUsers)
        {
            FillUsers();

        }
        loginStatus = LoginStatus.Success;
    }
    else
    {
        loginStatus = LoginStatus.Failure;
    }
});
progress.Report(loginStatus);
return loginStatus;
}
public async Task<LoginStatus> Login(IProgress<LoginStatus> progress,string userName, string password)
{
LoginStatus loginStatus = new LoginStatus();
loginStatus = LoginStatus.Attempt;
if (progress != null) { progress.Report(loginStatus); }
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    AppSetting setting = new AppSetting();
    SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(setting.GetConnectionString("cn").Replace("Integrated Security=True", $"User ID={userName};pwd={password};Integrated Security=False"));
    if (helper.HandShake())
    {
        setting.SaveConnectionString("conn", setting.GetConnectionString("cn").Replace("Integrated Security=True", $"User ID={userName};pwd={password};Integrated Security=False"));
        helper = new SqlHelper(setting.GetConnectionString("conn"));
        if (helper.HandShake())
        {
            _currentUser = userName;
            if (_users == null && fillUsers)
            {
                FillUsers();

            }
            loginStatus = LoginStatus.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            loginStatus = LoginStatus.Failure;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        loginStatus = LoginStatus.Failure;
    }
});
progress.Report(loginStatus);
return loginStatus;
}
```

Comment: UI elements should only be created, accessed, and/or updated on the UI thread. Don't do it in a `Task.Run`.

Comment: then how would you show a load screen while checking login credentials and they asking for login information if the user was not able to login?

Comment: You access all of the UI elements on the UI thread, pass any values you need from the UI as `string` or `int`, etc, to a Task. You await the Task or have the Task invoke on to the UI thread any return values back to the UI. The UI can then display the results of the Task. The Task cannot create, access, or update any UI directly.

Comment: This answer is not the correct way to do it. It should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity please post an example of how to do this

Comment: This this: https://pastebin.com/E1hRQWBB

Comment: Seems like my edit was correct then

Answer (score 3):

You're running into a deadlock due to this line:

```
LoadDataAsync().Wait();
```

When you execute `Task.Run` without `await` from a UI thread, and instead use `.Wait()`, it will create a deadlock. Once the new thread completes, it tries to communicate with the original UI thread saying that it's complete, but the UI thread is frozen `.Wait()`ing for it to complete.

Using `await` prevents the UI thread from freezing, while still waiting for the new thread to complete. As a rule of thumb, always use `await` when calling async code from the main UI thread.

Simply change your `ProgramMain` method to be an async Task and use await:

```
public async Task ProgramMain()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    await LoadDataAsync();
    _viewPageManager = new ViewPageManager(MainTabControl);
}
```

You'll likely still run into issues though because you create a `new UserLogin` dialog from a different thread. UI Elements should always be created and accessed from the original UI thread.

This is how I would write your `LoadDataAsync` code:

```
protected async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    StartUp.StartUpForm progressForm = new StartUp.StartUpForm();
    progressForm.Show();
    // 'await' long-running method by wrapping inside Task.Run
    bool handshakeSuccessful = await Task.Run(() =>
    {                
        AppSetting setting = new AppSetting();
        SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper(setting.GetConnectionString("cn"));
        return helper.HandShake();
    });

    if (!handshakeSuccessful)
    {
        UserLogin userLogin = new UserLogin();
        if(userLogin.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logged In");
            handshakeSuccessful = true;
        }
    }
    progressForm.Close();
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful and lead me in the right direction

Comment: UI elements should only be created, accessed, and/or updated on the UI thread. Don't do it in a `Task.Run`.